UserInfo.getsessionId() not working from the context of a console app to invoke salesforce apis from apex?
Im trying to invoke salesforce cpq apis from Apex. The Apex class sets Authorization as follows:
request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());

The class is exposed as an Action in a Flow.
The Flow is exposed in two Apps, one with Standard Navigation and one with Console Navigation. When the Flow runs from the context of a Standard App, the code works well and the call to the CPQ APIs works fine.
When the Flow is invoked from the Console App, call to the APIs fails with an error:  [{"message":"This session is not valid for use with the REST API","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]
I have tried to implement this using Named Credentials. How can I resolve this and invoke the apis from apex in the console app context?
I considered to utilize a connected app approach for this, but thought that it was not needed, as the callout is internal itself.

Are those tests for Standard Navigation and Console Navigation apps done as the same salesforce user?

Yes, I've tried this as the same user(my user)
